# Cannot multiply reference of generic's

Tags: generics, rust, struct, lifetime

I have a struct with two generic's

```
    pub struct Rectangle<T, U> {
    height: T,
    width: U,
    }
```

With a impl block

```
    impl< T, U> Rectangle<T, U>
{
    pub fn new(height: T, width: U) -> Self {
        Self { height, width }
    }

    pub fn area(&self) -> &U {
        &self.width * &self.height // Error: cannot multiply `&U` by `&T`
    }
}
```

> Even after Mul impl its not working

- [Code with ref](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=396af940638a1ff8316958b35d9294f8)

> Working fine if ref(&) is removed.

- [Code without ref](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=0ffb26dddd62a97745a0fb790a23b8a0)

I assume the efficient way would be passing reference rather than copying.How can i make this code compile with reference. [Code with ref](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=396af940638a1ff8316958b35d9294f8)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you assume that `&i32` implements `Mul<&i32, Output = &i32>`. It does not. Though there is a similar implementation that outputs `i32`.

```rust
// Error
// let r: &i32 = &100_i32 * &200_i32;

// Fine
let r: i32 = &100_i32 * &200_i32;
```

So to fix this, we change the trait bound and the function signature, and then fix minor lifetime errors.

```rust
impl<'a, 'b: 'a, T: 'a, U: 'b> Rectangle<T, U>
where
    &'b U: Mul<&'a T, Output = U>,
{
    fn new(height: T, width: U) -> Self {
        Self { height, width }
    }

    fn area(&'b self) -> U {
        &self.width * &self.height
    }
}
```

Now that I've given you the solution, I would recommend that you do not worry about copying trivial types. I think that references are more expensive in this case, unless you are doing some weird maths where T and U are not simple numbers, but some custom structs for which you implemented `Mul`, but I doubt it. First the pointers are put on the stack, which are likely 64 bits in size, and they need to be dereferenced to do the operation, which is slower than just putting the values on the stack, which may even be smaller in size than pointer, and they don't need to be dereferenced.